# I'm confused with this sentence. There are multiple verbs, and one is plural. Does this make the subject-verb agreement incorrect?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

**Sentence** -"Our pet alligator has been stalking neighborhood pets because my brother Billy forgets to feed the poor reptile."

My questions is two fold.
If the answer to my question is wrong, and the subject-verb agreement is correct, then can there be multiple subject-verb agreements in the same sentence?

Answer (score 1):

First, there are two clauses in the sentence. Each clause has a subject and a verb: `alligator -- has been stalking` and `Billy -- forgets`.

Second, which verb do you believe is in plural form?

Comment: I was thinking forgets but now i'm thinking "forgets" is just past tense, and that is why it has an "s" on the end. Is that correct?

Comment: The word "forgets" is a present-tense form which agrees with a third-person *singular* subject.  The singular "alligator" agrees with the singular "has", and the singular "Billy" agrees with the singular "forgets".  Singular present-tense verbs commonly end with -s.  Don't confuse that with plural nouns, which also commonly end with -s.

Comment: Hi Gary. Your great. I just have one more question. Even though both clauses have subject-verb agreements. Does the sentence lack parallelism?